# Function with arguments from other function

Tags: python

How can I create something like this:

```
def test(a)
    return a

def invoker(func):
    func() #here I need call the function twice and sum result (test function)

invoker(test(10), test(15))
```

Comment: Do you want `invoker` to actually _invoke_ functions given to it, or merely to sum the results given to it? The name says the former, your example says the latter. When you do `invoker(test(10)...)`, `test` will be called _before_ `invoker`, so `invoker` doesn't _invoke_ anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Arbitrary Argument Lists is what you are looking for: http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

```
def test(a):
    return a

def invoker(*args):
    print sum(args) # Prints 25
    print args # Prints (10, 15)

invoker(test(10), test(15))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
def add_many(func, *args):
    return reduce(add, map(func, args))
```

Simplified (credit goes to mbatchkarov):

```
def add_many(func, *args):
    return sum(map(func, args))
```

func is a callback with one argument, args is a list of values used by that callback. map built-in transforms args according to func. reduce serves as a prefix operator in Lisp-like languages (+ 1 2 3 4) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, same with reduce. add is just a + operator in callback form.

More generalized version (Python3):

```
from functools import reduce
def invoker(func, op, *args):
    return reduce(op, map(func, args))
```

Call like this (for example):

```
from operator import add
invoker(lambda x:x, add, 10, 15)  # returns 25
```

Comment: The special case of summation could be simplified as `return sum(map(func, args))`

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer generalized to simplified. :P Thanks though, nice to know.